# Problem with linking against libexpat in Boost Build - for building graphml

Tags: boost, boost-build, graphml

On my system, expat is located at

```
/usr/include/expat.h
/usr/include/expat_external.h
/usr/lib/libexpat.1.5.0.dylib
/usr/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
/usr/lib/libexpat.dylib
/usr/lib/libexpat.la
```

So I export the required variables for boost to build *graphml*

```
export EXPAT_INCLUDE=/usr/include
export EXPAT_LIBPATH=/usr/lib
```

then I run (where $DIR and $BOOST generate the paths I want the includes and libs to go)

```
./configure --includedir=$DIR/$BOOST --libdir=$DIR/$BOOST/lib \ 
            --with-libraries=test,graph
```

I get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lexpat collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

which boost says is caused by the line:

```
g++ -dynamiclib -install_name "libboost_graph-mt-1_35.dylib" -L"/usr/lib" 
    -o "bin.v2/libs/graph/build/darwin/release/macosx-version-10.4/threading-multi/libboost_graph-mt-1_35.dylib" 
    "bin.v2/libs/graph/build/darwin/release/macosx-version-10.4/threading-multi/read_graphviz_spirit.o" 
    "bin.v2/libs/graph/build/darwin/release/macosx-version-10.4/threading-multi/graphml.o"   
    -lexpat   -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -Wl,-dead_strip -no_dead_strip_inits_and_terms
```

I don't get how it's not finding the expat library with `-L"/usr/lib"` and `-lexpat` as arguments? My understanding is that /usr/lib/libexpat.dylib is exactly referenced as `-L"/usr/lib"` and `-lexpat`.

The Jamfile for building graphml is [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/trunk/libs/graph/build/Jamfile.v2). If `EXPAT_INCLUDE` and `EXPAT_LIBPATH` aren't set then it warns you (lines 39-41 of jamfile)

> warning: Graph library does not contain optional GraphML reader.
>   note: to enable GraphML support, set EXPAT_INCLUDE and
>   note: directories containing the Expat headers and libraries, respectively.

Comment: I think you are trying to create a stable build process?  You probably don't want to try and creating symbolic links to the library in a few other places to see if it finds the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another update:**
I don't see an .so or a .a file in your list of where EXPAT is... doesn't that seem a bit strange?  Normally it will create an alias for the library name

for example /usr/lib/libblah.so -> /usr/lib/libblaah.so.1.2

Is dynalib some Macintoshism (I don't use Macs much)

is .la the static version extension on this platform?

**Update:**

The quotes around the path seem troublesome...
-L"/usr/lib"

Try changing this to -L/usr/lib and -L /usr/lib

**Older stuff:**

The directive for the linker to include paths during the link step is -L.  You need to look for some linker flags to update to include -L path_to_expat.  I don't think the linker pays any attention to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I am not sure what documentation you have read to set EXPAT_INCLUDE or EXPAT_LIBPATH.

Comment: Here is the Jamfile (the build file) that tells me to set EXPAT_INCLUDE and EXPAT_LIBPATH https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/trunk/libs/graph/build/Jamfile.v2?rev=49008

Comment: The site has an expired ssl certificate :(.  I am not allowed to read it with the draconian settings on the computer I am on.  I think that if you cut and paste the final line and play with the -Wl (which I think are the linker options you may be able to get it to compile by hand.

Comment: Why would they have me set shell variables rather than pass the paths in as arguments like you do for --libdir?

Comment: There are some strange traditions in the open source community between projects that depend on each other.  When building Perl modules that depended on libraries I spent days upon days figuring out how modules emitted, detected, and configured their library paths and linker options.

Comment: Yeah, dylib is the mac dynamic library suffix. And, the jamfile is putting the -L path in quotes, so I don't know how to work around that besides running that gcc command by hand - like you mentioned,

Comment: Can you verify that the sym links in usr lib are correct and that eventually the /usr/lib actually points to something?  How about naming it .a and see maybe if has to be told to look for dynalib... I feel your pain.  It makes me a bit angry that someone decided to start using dynalib as an ext...

Comment: I installed expat separately (i.e. in /opt/local/lib) from the system installation (i.e. /usr/lib) and linked to it which resolved the problem.